# Isolating typescript variable declarations with long interfaces into own file

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering whats the best practice of declaring default values on variables, where the interface consists of many properties.

For example theres a following interface:

```
interface House {
  color: string,
  windows: number,
  width: number,
  height: number,
  depth: number,
  doors: number,
  address: string,
  postCode: string,
  city: string,
  ...
}
```

Now everywhere I want to use this interface, I need to provide a value for each of the properties. Even if I want to update just a couple properties at a time, I have to declare all of them, which pollutes the file unnecessarily. Now I know I can make the fields optional, but this is not what im looking for.

Is there a practice for separating the declaration of such variable into some different file?

Comment: Why not just use `Pick<House, properties>` to narrow the interface to the properties that you actually intend to use?

Comment: @ChrisHeald Lets say I want to update a redux state that is of type House|null, and at first (page) I only want to fill in some of the values.

Comment: You have to provide those properties somehow. So how, ideally, would you like to create a `House`? How, ideally, would you like to "update" a house? There are _a lot_ of ways to accomplish things like this, but they really depend on how you intend to create and manipulate `House`s.

Comment: I would have your sub-interface use Pick'd values and return a `Partial<House>` then.

Comment: @downtalo Is this what you mean? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIHsCuBnFBvAKGWQXQBt0oAuZbMKUAcwBojkB3UAE3XexpCYAtgCNorYj0r9kg0eIIBfAipiYQCMMHQhkQuAGsIGHBAAUABzhQtcMjQAK122QA8J3AD4AlDQ-42KAgwTChdQmJiUgpqZABydgALYEg4iUjOEB4+GgBGACZ0yXRpGkK2YgA6aqsbYDs2ZWUCNQ0tHWRMCy44SH8zRKxcPyGIZmRal0dnerd-HxHTZAjkIJCw5YrkasrB0yLtmpmG4iaVUhA6ZD3cZABePUNjUbM8EnJKGjiLUAM45EU3gIFyunDAiQAysAuBAACIlKD3TrdXrPUwDUbjN5SKAyADMgOBOmw5AglQojAxpm8yAA9LTlu8YjQfiADONMtkZAVxjj8QCgA

Comment: @AlexWayne Thank you for this, its a new technique for me. However, like you mentioned earlier, I still have to provide all the properties at some point. I guess I would just like to separate the declaration of default values into a different file, which I could then import when needed. Is this common practice and is there a naming convention for files/folders like this?

Comment: The answer again, depends on why it exists, and drifts into opinion which we try avoid as answers on this site. For example, in my backend node.js app, objects of these types come fully formed out of the database. The only time they don't is in tests so we have `fixtures` folder that contains a bunch of functions that make fake versions of things. But "fixtures" only makes sense if we're talking about tests here. So it really depends on your applications architecture, data model and conventions. There is no one recommend way to do something this general.

Comment: @AlexWayne My use case would be to partially update a state in redux after every form input, so a user wouldnt lose the already filled information in case the user accidentally navigates somewhere else, if it matters. I guess I just dont want to declare the default values of an object with 20+ properties in the component itself to make it cleaner.

Comment: Well if my link to the typescript playground is enough of an answer for you, I'd be happy to write it up. Otherwise I'm inclined this an highly opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

Your `House` type can probably benefit from [compositional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) modelling.

Looking over the members of the type, it seems like the entire type is composed of groups of logically related members. For example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnAThAziqBeKBvAUFKAQwWTQC4oVhEBLAOwHMBufKAYxtAqtsZYLAB7KgGFBcCN2r1muAL4tcoSFAAiNALYQ6KGoJ2YcrCWGAALCnQCuGgEYRE-KGYg0GZ4JZv3HrAO40cOZedg4sCrhK4NAAYhCEwFbIYlZ0wOhYeARwgoKIKCE+TgF0OX4FUNahvhFRKgDKoAA2EAAKiIJgGUYEbIJNeVK8srXK0AASglYo0FjwSKjoAGRqmtq6+stQcQlJEClpW40gLe2dKIoAZqlswHp0UFZgcAkQk9MQ86ToABRmUzMKO8ZgAaIgkRYUL6LACUFAAboJAj0oAB6VFQTRgFpaNIJe4AOiJ8lwQA)

```ts
type Address = {
  address: string;
  city: string;
  postCode: string;
};

type Dimensions = {
  depth: number;
  height: number;
  width: number;
};

type FeatureCounts = {
  doors: number;
  windows: number;
};

type StyleProps = {
  color: string;
};
```

The `House` type represents a combination of all of those groups of attributes:

```ts
type House = Address & Dimensions & FeatureCounts & StyleProps;
```

By breaking apart the groups of related properties, it then becomes easier to work with each of them as needed — for example, updating a house's address:

```ts
function updateHouseAddress (house: House, address: Address): void {
  // implementation...
}
```

And, as [@AlexWayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62076/alex-wayne) mentioned, TypeScript offers quite a few built-in [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) (e.g. [`Partial<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype), [`Pick<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys), [`Omit<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys), etc.) for deriving other types from existing type information.

See also:

- [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)
- [Interfaces vs. Intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#interfaces-vs-intersections)
- [Differences Between Type Aliases and Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces)